# RequestBody is null in controller

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I'm trying to send JSON object from frontend to backend via jQuery AJAX.
The ajax call is performed successfully on the requested path "/survey" with a POST method.
Problem is, my `@RequestBody final HmmSurveyForm hmmSurveyForm` has null values for my fields "answer1" and "heading".
When I checked request in google chrome developer request is sent:

[image]

[image]

But the response is null for populated fields from frontend:

[image]

I have following code in frontend:

```
postSurvey: function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.encodedContextPath + "/survey",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: ACC.hmmSurvey.getJSONDataForSurvey(),
            async: true,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("The following error occurred: " + textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        });
}

getJSONDataForSurvey: function () {
        var json = [];

        json.push({"answer1": "1"});
        json.push({"heading": "Test"});

        return JSON.stringify({"hmmSurveyForm": json});
}
```

and in backend:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/survey", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody HmmSurveyForm postSurvey(@RequestBody final HmmSurveyForm hmmSurveyForm, final Model model) {
    System.out.println(hmmSurveyForm);
    return hmmSurveyForm;
}

public class HmmSurveyForm {

    private String heading;
    private String answer1;

    // getter, setters
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring your RQ body incorrectly in JS

```js
var json = [];
json.push({"answer1": "1"});
json.push({"heading": "Test"});
console.log({"hmmSurveyForm": json});
```

which has the root `hmmSurveyForm` as an array of distinct objects, which has no relation to what your backend expects.

You should be using the code below;

```js
var json = {};
json["answer1"] = "1";
json["heading"] = "Test";
console.log({"hmmSurveyForm": json});
```

Check more on JSON Object in JS [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp)

Comment: @Kapparino you do pass the `JSON.stringify`'d version of the `json` right?

Comment: That's correct. I was missing JSON.stringify `getJSONDataForSurvey: function () {
        var json = {};

        json["answer1"] = "1";
        json["heading"] = "Test";

        return JSON.stringify(json);
    },` Thanks.